# C# open embedded zip-files

Tags: c#, zip

I have a program where I need to search an arbitrary number of nested zip-files. I was able to solve this in python 3 by taking the namelist of the archive at a given path, finding zip-files, opening them, converting the file to a byte string with BytesIO, and then calling the method again recursively on the bytestring. Like so:

```
def zip_dig(source_path, posts):

try:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source_path, 'r') as zip_ref:  # Open initial zip file, list contents
        for name in zip_ref.namelist():
            if re.search(r'\.zip$', name) is not None:
                if name.endswith('.zip'):
                    zfiledata = BytesIO(zip_ref.read(name))
                    zip_dig(zfiledata, posts)
except zipfile.BadZipFile:
    pass
return posts
```

I now need to solve this in C#, but I can't seem to find any equivalent solution.

I have googled extensively and looked through the documentation of the ZipFile and ZipArchive classes, but I can't seem to find similar workaround for the fact that the file reference comes in the form of a Stream rather than a String:

```
internal static List<BsonDocument> ZipDig(string path, List<BsonDocument> posts)
    {
        path = Path.GetFullPath(path);

        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(path))
        {
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
            {
                if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".zip", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {

                    posts = ZipDig(entry, posts);
                }
            }
        }


            return posts;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I should clarify, the zip files are often several gigabytes large and therefore extraction is not really and option from a time consumption perspective. I'm just finding a particular type of txt-file, reading them and entering the contents into a database.

Answer (score 3):

ZipArchive has a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158268(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes a stream.
Use that below the initial level of recursion.

Comment: Even for the 1st level of recursion and pass File.Open(path) as an argument.

Comment: I think that will require some restructuring of my code, but that could definitively work! Thanks!